# Spring kafka producer threads keep increasing

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We are using Kafka with Spring and we are currently doing some load testing on the application. Within few minutes of starting the load test Tomcat stops responding, on analyzing the thread dump I am seeing quite a large number of Kafka producer threads and assuming that this could be a reason why application hangs.The number of threads are quite high, i.e. within few minutes there are 200+ Kafka producer threads are there. Is there any way to close these producer threads. Given below is my Spring Kafka producer configuration.

**EDIT**:
      In our application we have a event pub/sub and I am using Kafka for publishing the events. **Number of partitions : 15, Concurrency : 5**

```
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaCustomPartitioner.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 16384);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 200);


    DefaultKafkaProducerFactory factory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    factory.setTransactionIdPrefix(serverId+"-tx-");
    // factory.setProducerPerConsumerPartition(false);
    return factory;
}

public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory(String groupId) {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG,"read_committed");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,"custom-group-id");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,60000);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG,5000);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG,20);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG,600000);
    props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "org.xxx.xxx.xxx");
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}


@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> customKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    //factory.setConcurrency(eventTopicConcurrency);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler());
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory("custom-group-id"));

    return factory;
}
```

Below are my publisher and subscriber code

```
@Override
public void publish(Event event) {
    //try {
        DomainEvent event = event.getDomainEvent();
        ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, Object>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(topicName,
                event.getMainDocumentId() != null ? event.getMainDocumentId() : null, event);

        future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, Object>>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, Object> result) {
                if(LOGGER.isDebugEnabled())
                    LOGGER.debug("Published event {} : {}",event.getEventName(), event.getEventId());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                LOGGER.error("Failed to publish event {} : {} ", event.getEventName(), event.getEventId());
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        });
    }
```

Listener: We have more than one subscriber for an event, so when we receive an event from Kafka we spawn new threads for each subscribers to process that event and when all of them completes the processing we commit the offset.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.event.topic.name}-#{ClusterConfigSplitter.toClusterId('${cluster.info}')}", concurrency="${kafka.event.topic.concurrency}", clientIdPrefix="${web.server.id}-event-consumer", containerFactory = "customKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void eventTopicListener(Event event, Acknowledgment ack)
        throws InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

    if(LOGGER.isDebugEnabled())
        LOGGER.debug("Received event {} : {}", event.getDomainEvent().getEventName(), event.getDomainEvent().getEventId());

    DomainEvent domainEvent = event.getDomainEvent();

    List<EventSubscriber> subcribers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String failedSubscriber : event.getSubscribersToRetry()) {
        subcribers.add(eventSubcribers.get(failedSubscriber));
    }

    CountDownLatch connectionLatch = new CountDownLatch(subcribers.size());

    List<String> failedSubscribers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (EventSubscriber subscriber : subcribers) {

        taskExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tenantContext.setTenant(domainEvent.getTenantId());
                DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
                def.setName(domainEvent.getEventId() + "-" + subscriber.getClass().getName());
                def.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);

                TransactionStatus status = txManager.getTransaction(def);

                try {
                    subscriber.handle(domainEvent);
                    txManager.commit(status);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    LOGGER.error("Processing event {} : {} failed for {} - {}", domainEvent.getEventName(), domainEvent.getEventId(), ex);

                    txManager.rollback(status);
                    failedSubscribers.add(subscriber.getClass().getName());
                }

                connectionLatch.countDown();

                if(LOGGER.isDebugEnabled())
                    LOGGER.debug("Processed event {} : {} by {} ", domainEvent.getEventName(), domainEvent.getEventId(), subscriber.getClass().getName());
            }
        });

    }

    connectionLatch.await();

    ack.acknowledge();

    if(failedSubscribers.size()>0) {

        eventPersistenceService.eventFailed(domainEvent, failedSubscribers, event.getRetryCount()+1);

    }




}
```

TransactionManager

```
    @Bean
@Primary
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory factory,@Qualifier("common-factory") EntityManagerFactory commonFactory, ProducerFactory producerFactory){

    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(factory);

    JpaTransactionManager commonTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    commonTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(commonFactory);

    KafkaTransactionManager kafkaTransactionManager= new KafkaTransactionManager(producerFactory);

    return new ChainedKafkaTransactionManager(kafkaTransactionManager,commonTransactionManager,transactionManager);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to write a more complete answer to help others who might find this question.

When using transactions, by default, we have to create a new producer for each `group/topic/partition` combination (assuming the transactions are started by a consumer thread); this is so that a producer can be properly fenced if a rebalance occurs.

The 2.5 kafka-clients has an improved algorithm that improves this situation and we no longer need all of those producers.

However, the brokers have to be upgraded to 2.5.0 in order to use this feature.

The upcoming 2.5.0.RELEASE (due tomorrow) allows the use of this new threading model for transactional producers.

The [release candidate](https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/30/spring-for-apache-kafka-2-5-0-release-candidate) is available for testing.

Documentation about the new feature is [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.0.RC1/reference/html/#exactly-once).

However, you have disabled creation of producers that provide proper producer fencing.

```
factory.setProducerPerConsumerPartition(false);
```

So in this case, you should see the producers being cached; it would be unusual to have so many producers unless you have a huge concurrency on your listener containers and producing at very high volume.

The producer factory does not currently support limiting the size of the cache.

Perhaps you could edit your question to explain a bit more about what your application is doing and show some more code/configuration.

Comment: I have added more code, please see whether it gives any idea

Comment: sorry, after setting `factory.setProducerPerConsumerPartition(false);` I didn't run the load test, the observation given was for the default one, still 200+ looks like a quite big number, will check the thread count tomorrow after setting `producerPerConsumerPartition = false`

Comment: How many subscribers? Given that architecture I am not surprised you end up with a lot of producers if the number of subscribers is high. I presume `publish()` is called from `subscriber.handle()`. Perhaps consider using a pool of subscribers instead to limit the number of concurrent producers you need.

Comment: Sorry I posted that before your second comment; however, given that you are running the producers on new threads (not the container thread), I doubt that producer factory setting will make a difference since you're using producers from the cache not the producer that the container will start (assuming you have injected the CKTM into the container). However, it makes no sense to use a transactional container since your producers are not participating in that transaction.

Comment: I am not able to understand your first part of the comment, can you elaborate - "however, given that you are running the producers on new threads (not the container thread), I doubt that producer factory setting will make a difference since you're using producers from the cache not the producer that the container will start". Also why do you say the producers are not participating in the transaction, the method which invoke publish  method is under @Transactional

Comment: You don't show your container factory; if you injected the `ChainedKafkaTransactionManager` into the container(s) then the container will start a transaction on the listener thread; any `KafkaTemplate` operations **on that thread** will participate in that transaction. Since you are using an executor, that won't be the case, and your  executor threads will each start a new transaction. (If you are **not injecting the CKTM into the container(s)** then it's not a problem). That property  `producerPerConsumerPartition` is only relevant when producers are created via the listener container.

Comment: ContainerFactory code I have already posted, anyhow I want to start a different transaction for each subscriber. Also please let me know the Kafka configuration that I have done can be optimised in anyway

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the container factory - that's good; no wasted unused producers there then. What's the average number of subscribers in the events? Given concurrency 5, if you are seeing 200 producers, it would imply there are 40 subs per event. Another way to limit it would be to limit the pool size on the task executor.

Comment: we are having 45 events and an average of 1.5 subscribers per event. Yeah, will try to limit the task executor pool size